# mod-rewrite redirect url with query string to static url

Tags: mod-rewrite

This has resulted in much hair pulling. I'm trying to redirect a URL with a query string to a static-looking URL - I want the URL to actually change if the URL with query string is entered.

Thus, if the user navigates to:

http://mysite.com/index.cfm?event=page.product&productid=170&languageid=en

then mod_rewrite would redirect to:

http://mysite.com/en/products/170

I have tried this in my htaccess file (and the htaccess works):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event=page\.product&productid=(.*)&languageid=(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.cfm$ /%2/products/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

However, this does not seem to be working. I've looked all over stackoverflow but cannot find what I'm looking for.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Very strange that your code isn't working. So here are my advices, that may put you on the right track:

---

(1)

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

(2)

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)